# Can workflow routing via WCF routing be in the same project as the workflow service itself?

Tags: wcf, workflow-foundation-4

Our firm is in the beginning stages of implementing business processes using workflow foundation. Much of what I have read online suggests that we prepare ahead of time for changes to the workflows (most of which will be breaking changes) and so we are implementing WCF routing in front of our workflows to handle versioning.

I have it working with the WCF routing in a separate project than the workflow service project, but would prefer, if possible, to have the routing in the same project, since we are hosting the services in a virtual directory application under the main web site. We would prefer to not have more virtual directory applications than necessary.

I read somewhere online (and can't find it right now) that the actual WCF routing implementation cannot be in the same project as the workflow service. If this really is the case, can someone explain why this is so? What would prevent this configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be interested in reading the post why this isn't possible as I can't think of an immediate problem preventing this. After all the RoutingService only accepts and forward SOAP messages and doesn't need to know anything about particular workflow versions.